# glob() works when on a local testing server, but breaks online

Tags: php, glob

I'm having issues with a simple php snippet in my code. This is supposed to make a listing of all the photos in a directory and make a list of `<li>` tags with the images inside. The problem is that it works on my local testing server, but when I put it up online, the source comes back without any `<li>` tags.

```
foreach(glob("./assets/images/frontpage/*jpg",GLOB_BRACE) as $fname){
 echo "<li><img src=\"/assets/images/frontpage/" . baseName($fname) . "\" alt=\"\" /></li>";
}
```

I've tried the script with `./assets/` and `assets/`, neither work online but both work locally. Is this a problem with the server or with my script? And how would I test to see if this is a server problem?

Comment: What if you specify `*.jpg`, not `*jpg`? And what gives `var_dump(is_dir('./assets/images/frontpage'));` to you?

Comment: Does "without any `<li>` tags" mean the images are still there, or does nothing display?

Comment: @zerkms That wouldn't change anything.

Comment: @ceejayoz: I remember I had experienced issues without `.` before extension, not sure what OS it was with though

Comment: 1) What server are you running on remotely?  There are some limitations of this function listed in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).  2) Do you have full access to that directory on your server?

Comment: @zerkms Glob doesn't really care about file extensions, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `glob()` without `GLOB_BRACE`. I've found that on some servers it just don't work. It's not needed in Your case.